# In GAELYK, how do i store the form-submitted params variable as Text type in entity/datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, google-cloud-datastore, gaelyk

Im using Gaelyk to build an app on Google app engine, I have a form that submits contents of a text-area (which exceeds 500 characters), to be saved in datastore.

so here is what i did :-

```
//add-a-book.groovy
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity

def book = new Entity("Book")
book.title = params.title
book.story = params.description
book.save()
```

So, this code does not work as book.story is being considered as String and hence the 500 chars limit on it,

now how do i define it as a datatype of Text.. i understand its a beginners question, can anybody pls help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to do

```
book.story = params.description as Text
```

The converters are described in the second yellow box (at time of posting) [on the tutorial page](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/tutorial/app-engine-shortcuts)

Comment: yeah I've tried that earlier it did not work, i get this error

    "unable to resolve class Text"

should i import anything else apart from the Entity class ?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text

Comment: ah ha silly me, now its working.. brilliant ! :) thanks a million tim !
ps: i see ure from Uk as well.. so coding late hours ha ?

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Gaelyk 1.0 release, the handling of Text vs String is now transparent: you can set and retrieve a property on an Entity by just using Strings. So even if you doo book.story = params.description and the description is longer than 500 characters, automatically, Gaelyk will wrap that String in a Text instance. When retrieving a property of type Text from the entity, like book.story, you will get a String, even if the underlying type is really a Text. It's unwrapped automatically.